# WebView Javascript cross domain from a local HTML file

Tags: javascript, android, cross-domain, android-webview, same-origin-policy

I load a local html file (from assets folder) to the app WebView.
In the HTML I run a jQuery.getJSON(url). the url is a remote server.

This action fails, and I'm guessing because of a different origin issue (cross domain). I run the same file on chrome and there it specifically says so.

Is there a way to allow the WebView in Android to load data from remote server on a local loaded HTML file?

Comment: Did you try adding the "&jsoncallback=?" or "callback=?" to your URL ?

Comment: Did you try with the ".ajax" method instead of "getJSON" ? with ".ajax", if you put in the options "data-type:jsonp", it should work for you!

Comment: won't the remote server need to specifically support JSONP for that to work? I'm not super familiar with the rules of webviews, are they different from desktop browsers?

Comment: I have a callback. in fact when running the html from the built-in web browser of Eclipse it works fine. haven't tried to simply call ".ajax" but why would it be different? I'll try anyway...

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I have hit the exact same problem and can't fathom it out (as another data point, the exact same form works okay on an embedded browser on iPhone).

Answer (score 60):

Today morning I found solution that seems to be working.

## The Java part

**Initialize your WebView:**

```
WebView _webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_webview_in_layout);
```

**get WebView settings:**

```
WebSettings settings = _webView.getSettings();
```

**set following settings:**

```
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true); //Maybe you don't need this rule
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

**now you can load your your html file by standard way:**

```
_webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

## The Javascript part

**Create XHR request by standard way**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "http://google.com", false);
xhr.send();
```

**Print the result somewhere**

```
document.body.innerHTML = xhr.responseText
```

> **NOTICE:**
>   This procedure works only on  API level 16 or higher (At least the documentation says that).

Comment: According to the documentation for setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs and setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs, they used to be set to true for ICS and older.  Starting in JellyBean they turned it off.  If you are trying to load a local JS file from a local HTML page, then you'll need to enable these.

Comment: Get the following: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHTTPRequest exception 101

Comment: great ans :) perfect solution :) u saved my day.thanks a ton.

Comment: Life saver, hot stuff congrats!! For me all I needed was `settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);`

Comment: Perfect, this is what i was needed

Comment: You Perfect :)))

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add the internet permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also make sure you are using JSONP requests (don't forget the &callback=? as stated above)

Answer (score 1):

> I load a local html file (from assets folder) to the app WebView

Note that you failed to say how you are doing this. I am going to guess that it was by a `loadUrl()` on a `file:///android_asset` URL.

> Is there a way to allow the WebView in Android to load data from remote server on a local loaded HTML file?

Try using `loadDataWithBaseURL()` to load the content, supplying a URL on the remote server as the base URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls wont work from local file system. More over it will become cross-domain. So it wont work. It worked in eclipse, becuz you tried from local server.

Answer (score 0):

A solution we used was to use Android to get the update files from the server, place them and overwrite files in the web folder, and then browse.