# Hello, is this generelly possible to show only one div from html-url?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to display only **one** div from a Website.

--

this site shows the hole site-content http://www.dict.cc/?s=house  (*house* should be dynamic, this search-expression isn't fix.)

and now the result should view only the div with the picture. but I don't know to do this.
 I found out, that this div called "slide0".
 I have this: ____________________________>   but the result should look like this:

[image] __________>[image]

Comment: Is your page on the same domain as the div you are trying to access?

Comment: @Lance: when you copy my code in a file and open it with the browser, then it should work. but my code doesn't work. (no it is not the same domain) ..mmh

Comment: I see the whole page in the div.  What do you see?  And what do you want?

Comment: @Lance: Yes, i also see the whole page in the div. - but i only want to see the house like above. (it is the div: slide0)

Comment: I believe the Same Origen Policy will prevent you from doing this, at least this way.  Do you have PHP installed on your server?

Comment: @Lance: i don't know if php will work.. it should be placed in Android (WebView)

Comment: You would use php to retrieve the div from the remote page and then insert it into your final page.

Comment: @Lance: and how would that code looks like?

Comment: Give me a few minutes.  I'm working on it now and will post it as an answer below when it's done.

Comment: Okay, the way they build the page, that's not going to work either.  What, exactly, is your desired result?  Do you just want the picture of the house?

Comment: @Lance: yes, i just want the piture of the house.. ..i don't get it. :/

Comment: Okay, @user3875103, then I think you are over complicating this a great deal.  I will post my answer below.

Comment: Same Origin Policy can be [disabled for a WebView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13740831/2784939), then you'd just use an Ajax call to get the data you need

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, the url

```
"http://www.dict.cc/?s=house"
```

returns the bytes representing an image.

If this is true, why not just use an image instead of a div?

```
<body>
<img id="result">
</body>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {   
            $("#result").src("http://www.dict.cc/?s=house");
    });
</script>
```

However, it looks like you're trying to use an image from another site. If so, you'll need permission to do that, and then when you get permission, simply use the complete URL of the image, not the entire web page URL.

Comment: The link doesn't return an image, it returns a web page.

Comment: "If I understand correctly, the url returns the bytes representing an image."

Comment: but, the URL from image is not always the same. It depends to the link. 

...cause http://www.dict.cc/?s=house can also be http://www.dict.cc/?s=talbe

Comment: @user3875103 Are you wanting to display someone else's website within your own? Is that what you're after?

Comment: i want to show a part(the div) from another website within my website.

Comment: @Blamkin86: thanks for this idea, but i don't know to solve it. :/ 
 ..can you post the code for my example, please. :-)

Comment: I'm not comfortable doing so. Please read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: now this contains my body:
`<iframe id="frameID" src="http://www.dict.cc/?s=house"/>`
and which way should i select for the solution?
1)
`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frameID').load(function(){
        $('#frameID').contents().find('slide0').html('test it!!');
    });
});`
2) `document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML`
or 3)`$('#frameID').contents().find('div#slide0).html();` ?
i don't understand how to solve.. :(